# fetching redis cache into django rest framework serializer

Tags: django, caching, serialization, redis, celery-task

I'm using redis for cache backend. I am trying to fetch redis cache data from serializer.

my code is :

```
class CocView(APIView):
"""
Celery and Redis Usage
"""
def get(self,request):

    data = cache.get('alldata')
    print "In the Cache",data
    if not data:
        print "in the database"
        data = Coc.objects.values('cache_id', 'username', 'email')
        test_result=mytask.delay(data) 
        test_result=mytask.delay() 

    serializer = CocSerializer(data, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

I am updating already existing data in my database using PUT.

I am passing redis cache data into serializer which is not updated but still it's showing updated data from database.

It means my serializer is automatically fetching data from the database.
I don't Know how it is going.

In my settings.py I have following middleware's for redis.

```
'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
```

In my task.py I have following task.

```
 from __future__ import absolute_import
 from app.models import Coc
 from app.celery import app
 from django.core.cache import cache
 from app.serializers import *
 from app.views import *

 @app.task
 def mytask(data):
    try:
        dataa = data
        cache.set('alldata', dataa,60*45)
        return 

    except ValueError:
        return "error"
```

If anyone have any suggestions about it's implementation, Please let us know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your shell

```
from django.core.cache import cache
```

and then type

```
cache.get('alldata')
```

if it returns none that means your cache is not being set with the corrresponding key. In this case proceed by settings the cache with the statement:

```
cache.set('alldata') = {<your data>}
```

This will set the cache for you and then it should work with the data coming from cache.

The data which you are receiving is coming out to be `None` or `empty` and hence it is querying the database everytime you try sending serializer the data.

Comment: Actually, we are setting our cache in the celery task file.

Comment: first of all I need to understand what was the reason for `dataa = data` :P, anyways jokes aside, the reason I can think of that your cache is not set is because your celery task did not run and hence could not set the cache for you or another reason I can think of is that your celery task might have run successfully but you were accessing the cache before the task actually ran and hence you get a none data. For this try to set the cache not as a celery task but set it in some script and then try to access.